# Two line charts as fill delimiter?

Tags: ios-charts

Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: it requires you to rewrite the renderer to draw the curve and fill the rect. Pretty advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for the same approach... As @Wingzero said, his solution requieres a pretty advanced knowledge on CoreGraphics. What I did is modified the framework and make the lines render in front of the content. With that, Added 2 lines: the first one with a fill color green with an alpha of 0.5 and the second one with a fill color of the **same** color of the background color and a alpha of 1 :)